# collapsing "drop" up nav menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

A slow slide up and down would be nice to add, as well as an auto close when a new section is opened. I think I can find the attribute for the sliding option, but how would previous sections be closed as new sections are opened? Also what would be best for closing the menu Icon if someone clicks outside the menu? Also, also, considering my 2 script functions are exactly the same, with the exceptions of, `classlist.toggle("change")`and `getElementsByClassName('')`, there has to be a way to use 1 call function for both instances, no?

```js
//Script
function menuIcon(x){
 /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
 to highlight the button that controls the panel */
 x.classList.toggle("change");

 /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
 var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
 for (var i = 0; i < panel.length; i++) {
  if (panel[i].style.display === "block") {
  panel[i].style.display = "none";
  } else {
  panel[i].style.display = "block";
  }
 }
}

function menuSub(x){
 /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
 var subM = document.getElementsByClassName('subItem'+x);
 for (var i = 0; i < subM.length; i++) {
  if (subM[i].style.display === "block") {
  subM[i].style.display = "none";
  } else {
  subM[i].style.display = "block";
  }
 }
}
```

```css
   
body {
  font-family: Georgia; 
  color: #444; 
}

.menuShell {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  width: 105px;
}

.menuLogo {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 33%;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #666666;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

div.panel {
  background-color: #666;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}

div.item:hover {
  background-color: #222;
}

.item {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.subItem, .subItem1, .subItem2, .subItem3, .subItem4 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: none;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuShell">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="subItem1">Menu1.1</div>
    <div class="subItem1">Menu1.2</div>
   <div class="item" onclick="menuSub(1)">Menu1</div>
    <div class="subItem2">Menu2.1</div>
    <div class="subItem2">Menu2.2</div>
   <div class="item" onclick="menuSub(2)">Menu2</div>
    <div class="subItem3">Menu3.1</div>
    <div class="subItem3">Menu3.2</div>
   <div class="item" onclick="menuSub(3)">Menu3</div>
    <div class="subItem4">Menu4.1</div>
    <div class="subItem4">Menu4.2</div>
   <div class="item" onclick="menuSub(4)">Menu4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuLogo" onclick="menuIcon(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <!--Menu bars-->
</div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific, what's the problem with the code, something not working? If You want to get single element from the document, assign it an ID and use `getElementById` method.

Comment: You should ask specific questions. As @KasperZiemianek said, you can assign an id with the `id="some-id"` attribute and get a reference to the element with `document.getElementById('some-id')`. For the sliding effects you can use CSS transitions on the `width` property.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being too general. I'm still very novice with scripting, so I'm doing my best to work it out. With regard to the getElementsByClass, My issue is using the class index [0] to target the element. My assumption is that I need to add a for() loop to target all elements with the specified class.

Comment: yes a for loop will work. getElementsByClassName(...) returns a HTMLCollection, which is an array of elements with the given class name and that array can be looped through. Do you need help with the loop? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: Yes, thank you. As in my example, when item 4 is clicked, I would like subItem 4.1, and subItem 4.2 to both change from display: none to block. I just don't really understand the for loop syntax too well. I know what it's doing, I just don't know how to use it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I worked it out with the for statement. I'm updating the source now. Any suggestions for improvements would be greatly appreciated.